# web.xml for jackson 2.1.3

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

What should I have in my web.xml to be able to use version 2.1.3 of jackson ?

when using 1.9 I had to have:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;com.rewardy.ws</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but this seems obsolete and I can find the docs to make it work the same.
(or maybe I am still missing some files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add Jackson 2.x jars, including JAX-RS provider (for JSON, and perhaps XML). That will auto-register, and you should not need to set POJOMappingFeature at all.

Comment: It did not seem to work for me without the POJOMappingFeature so amybe my serialization is currently some type of a mixture.
can you please explain what exactly is controllled by POJOMappingFeature  ?

Comment: With Jackson 1.x, that features is required, with 2.0 not. Difference is just that Jackson 2.x JAX-RS JSON provider includes service metadata (META-INF/services/...) to auto-register it as the default provider. POJOMappingFeature, on the other hand, is what Jersey Servlet checks to do registration explicitly.